# Where can I find public financial data for private companies?

Tags: data-request, finance

I'm looking for financial data sets of private companies that state their annual revenue, market value..etc. I'm doing so to be able to research their revenue vs their purchase history from us so I can build a predictive model.

Comment: This isn't really a data science question per-se. I hate that mods can close questions - that should never happen - but in your case, I just don't see anyone being able to give you a reasonable answer and still stay in the spirit of a data science forum.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for. But if by purchase history you mean acquisitions or merger, you could have a look at [crunchbase](https://www.crunchbase.com/search/acquisitions).

They will show an overview about acquisitions and known details such as acquisition price.